# adding page types in menu

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I believe what I am trying to achieve is quite easy but I am failing to grasp what is needed here.

I want a section in the admin panel... lets say "page sections"

under that, I want to be able to add multiple post types. i.e. lets say

"add member", "add foo", "add bar" ...

I currently have

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_item' );
add_action( 'init', 'add_item2' );
function add_item(){
    register_post_type('item1', array(
        'label' => 'Item label',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'capabilities' => array(

        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'puds'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            'post-formats'
        )
    ) );
}
function add_item2(){
register_post_type('item2', array(
    'label' => 'Item label 2',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'capabilities' => array(

    ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'puds'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'custom-fields',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'page-attributes',
        'post-formats'
    )
) );
```

}

which would generate

[image]

but i want one menu heading with more than one menu selection...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, try this:

```
'show_ui' => false,
'menu_position' => 'edit.php?post_type=main_posttype or registered section'
```

For example if you want it under Themes it would be:

```
'menu_position' => 'themes.php'
```

This on your post type registering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might check the labels docs for post types like this:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Book', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'book'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Book'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Book'),
    'new_item' => __('New Book'),
    'all_items' => __('All Books'),
    'view_item' => __('View Book'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Books'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No books found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No books found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Books')

  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 
  register_post_type('book',$args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Check: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: but that doesn't answer the question... I have already got that far...